# How to create a program that can read all the images in folder using Boost and OpenCV?

Tags: c++, boost, opencv

What I want is simple: I need to open all images in a folder (I dont care for subfolders but it would be great to be able to search subfolders) and turn them into a vector of `IplImage*`s  so I can use Boost.Foreach to loop through each image. How can I achieve this?

Comment: if you use C++, use `cv::Mat`, not `IplImage*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [boost filesystem](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-boostfs/index.html) to find all the images files in a directory.

Then cvLoadImage or cv:imread to read each file