# conflict between Armadillo and ofxOpenCv

Tags: c++, openframeworks, armadillo

I am using Armadillo as my matrix library. At the same time, I use OpenFrameworks in order to develop my codes. When I try to use ofxOpenCv together with Armadillo, I get the following errors:

/usr/include/armadillo_bits/traits.hpp: At global scope:
/usr/include/armadillo_bits/traits.hpp: In instantiation of ‘const bool arma::is_arma_type >::value’:
../../../addons/ofxOpenCv/libs/opencv/include/opencv2/core/operations.hpp:753:23:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/armadillo_bits/traits.hpp:584:28: error: ‘cv::’ is/uses anonymous type
/usr/include/armadillo_bits/traits.hpp:584:28: error:   trying to instantiate ‘template struct arma::is_subview_elem2’
/usr/include/armadillo_bits/traits.hpp:584:28: error: ‘cv::’ is/uses anonymous type
.
.
.
It seems to me that there is a conflict between the Armadillo and ofxOpenCv, but I am not sure how to solve this problem.
Could anybody give some hints to  resolve this problem?
Regards,
Tohid

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have polluted your namespace by calling "using namespace arma" in one or more header files before including your other library (see the accepted answer to [Conflict between Boost, OpenCV and Eigen libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327325/conflict-between-boost-opencv-and-eigen-libraries)).

You should not use the "using ... " directive in header files because depending on the order you include them in, you might include that header file, then another header file whose class definitions depend on an unpolluted namespace.

So where to put them? C++ doesn't allow you to put them inside a class definition because it could cause ambiguity with the scope. You are allowed to write "using namespace  " inside the definition of a class member function, so I'd recommend doing that wherever you need your armadillo data structures. Everywhere else, just scope it, e.g. arma::colvec or arma::mat, etc.